# Remove multiple rows if condition for one row is met

Tags: r, na, delete-row

I have the following dataset:

```
ID   value
abc    1
abc    NA
abc    2
def    5
def    1 
def    4
```

I know how to identify the ID of the row that contains a NA .
What I want to do is to delete all rows with the ID if one row contains a NA.
In this case: One row of abc shows an NA, thus all rows with ID = abc should be removed, so that the dataframe looks like this:

```
ID   value
def    5
def    1 
def    4
```

Comment: Using `dplyr` : `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(!is.na(value)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the negated `!` `%in%` of *ID* which have an `NA` *to delete all rows with the ID if one row contains a NA*.

```
x[!x$ID %in% unique(x$ID[is.na(x$value)]),]
#   ID value
#4 def     5
#5 def     1
#6 def     4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using DF shown reproducibly in the Note at the end `ave` creates a vector which is TRUE for each element that is part of an `ID` group in which any of the elements are NA and then we `subset` to all but those.

```
subset(DF, !ave(value, ID, FUN = anyNA))
```

giving:

```
   ID value
4 def     5
5 def     1
6 def     4
```

Using [de Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) this could be equivalently expressed as:

```
subset(DF, ave(!is.na(value), ID, FUN = all))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "ID   value
abc    1
abc    NA
abc    2
def    5
def    1 
def    4"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `subset` with `table`

```
 subset(df1, ID %in% names(which(!table(ID, is.na(value))[, 2])))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, .SD[!any(is.na(value))], ID]
    ID value
1: def     5
2: def     1
3: def     4
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "def"
), value = c(1L, NA, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```