# Conditionally remove rows in R

Tags: r, statistics

Dataframe:

```
A ; B
x   1
x   7
y   2
y   3
z   9
z   1
```

I want to remove all rows where A=x and A=z because x and z have value 1 in column B. Therefore, the dataframe must look like this:

```
A ; B
y   2
y   3
```

Thanks,

Comment: See: [Remove multiple rows if condition for one row is met](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66531815/10488504)

Answer (score 0):

```
my.data.frame <- subset(data , A != "x" | A != "z")
```

Btw, duplicate of [How to combine multiple conditions to subset a data-frame using "OR"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `subset`

```
> subset(df, ! A %in% c("x","z"))
  A B
3 y 0
4 y 0
```

**data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c("x", "x", "y", "y", "z", "z"), B = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My df has thousands of rows, so I want to remove the rows based on column B values.

Answer (score 0):

a `data.table` approach

```
library( data.table )
DT <- fread("A  B
x   1
x   7
y   2
y   3
z   9
z   1")


DT[ copy(DT)[, temp := sum(B == 1), by = A ]$temp == 0, ]

#    A B
# 1: y 2
# 2: y 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Column B does not always have 1 or 0 values. I want to remove all rows in column A that at least once have a value of 1 in column B.

Comment: see updated answer.. also, if B has other values than 0 or 1, you should probably add some in your sample data..

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now my question is more like my real base.